# Bundle install lingers too much

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, bundle, osx-yosemite

I updated ruby form 2.2.0 to 2.3.1, i'm using RVM, but every time i use bundle install it takes too much to run the code. I'm using OS X Yosemite ¿Does anyone have idea what could it be happening?

Answer (score 2):

I've had same issues before, but really bundle install sometimes just takes a long time to work.

As a temporary solution, you can change the address of the GEMFILE to get HTTPS to HTTP which expedites the process, but don't forget to change it back.

Also, there's been news that the new bundle version is experiencing some problem with slow updates. If that's your case, you could do

```
gem list | grep bundler

gem uninstall bundler -v existing-version-number

gem install bundler -v 1.11.2
```

To work with the version of bundle that doesn't have any known issue with speed.